# Event receiver for twice addition of same item on sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint custom list '**Contacts**' where items get created.I want to write a event receiver for blocking of duplicate item entry here say name(column of list).

Can anyone please explain how can I achieve this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting on StackOverflow. Your SharePoint questions you can post on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ dedicated for SP only.

About your problem - it's not required for you to craete an event receiver to achive your goal. If you have only one column with unique value so to avoid duplicate values in the list you can use OOTB SharePoint column property which can be set using UI "Enforce unique values". This method is valuable only for one column to be checked.

See [this](http://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/prevention-of-duplicate-entries-based-on-two-or-more-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/) post for more information.

Hope it helps,

Andrew